# Adsense with jquery-ui-map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, adsense

You can see below, my code to show a map and markers (from Json):

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function() { 
    $.getJSON( '../js/locate.php', function(data) { 
        $.each( data.markers, function(i, marker) {
            var mapvalue=new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude);  

            $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
                'tags': [''+marker.category+''],
                'position': mapvalue, 
                'bounds': true,                             
                'icon':'../images/'+marker.category+'.png',
                'animation':google.maps.Animation.DROP
            }).click(function() {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': ''+marker.category+'<BR><div id="cust_content"></div>' }, this);
                setTimeout("opencust(\'" +marker.id+"\');",100);
            });                 
        });                                      
    });  
});
```

How can I include the new adsense script on my map: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advertising#AdvertisingAdUnit

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what are you trying to do here ?

Comment: I'm just trying to add an adsense ads on my map. It is easy with google script, but I can't find a way to use it with the jquery-ui-map library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little research I made it work with few changes. You need to perform the following steps.

1. First include Adsense in your Google Maps JS. Notice the addition of **libraries=adsense&**

   ```
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=adsense&sensor=true"></script>
   ```
2. Modify your JS as below. Notice **$('#map_canvas').gmap('get','map')**

   ```
   $('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function() {
       $.getJSON( '../js/locate.php', function(data) {
           $.each( data.markers, function(i, marker) {
               var mapvalue=new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude);
                   $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
                   'tags': [''+marker.category+''],
                   'position': mapvalue,
                   'bounds': true,
                   'icon':'../images/'+marker.category+'.png',
                   'animation':google.maps.Animation.DROP
               }).click(function() {
                   $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': ''+marker.category+'<BR><div id="cust_content"></div>' }, this);
                   setTimeout("opencust(\'" +marker.id+"\');",100);
               });
           });
       });
       var adUnitDiv = document.createElement('div');
       var adUnitOptions = {
           format: google.maps.adsense.AdFormat.HALF_BANNER,
           position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP,
           backgroundColor: '#c4d4f3',
           borderColor: '#e5ecf9',
           titleColor: '#0000cc',
           textColor: '#000000',
           urlColor: '#009900',
           map: $('#map_canvas').gmap('get','map'),
           visible: true,
           publisherId: 'YOUR_PUBLISHER_ID'
       };
       adUnit = new google.maps.adsense.AdUnit(adUnitDiv, adUnitOptions);
   });
   ```